# How does Java affect the client-side?

Tags: java

I seem to be confused on a few levels of understanding Java, here is what I am curious about:

1. Is Java a client-side and server-side language?
2. Is it more a client-side or server-side, if both are applicable?

I don't know if this is the correct way to put this, if it isn't, please kindly me inform me of where this question would do better.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Well that's nice, two votes down and a close option selected. Thanks for the help guys! :)

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "server" or "client-side" language.

Comment: Or why it performs poorly. Compared to what? According to who?

Comment: Front-end and back-end? JavaScript is a client-side language. PHP is a server-side language. I want to know if Java is both.

Comment: You're getting downvotes because you haven't shown any research, and your third point is at best incorrect, and at worst just trolling. The answers to your question are: 1. both, 2. neither, 3. it doesn't.

Comment: It doesn't really help to distinguish "client side" and "server side" languages. Java can be used to write either, as can JavaScript (Node.js), python, ruby, ...

Comment: You have to do a good research before post something like this here

Comment: A language is a way of telling a computer what to do. Clients and servers are both computers. So, while languages _tend_ to be used in certain ways, nothing stops you from using it in a less-popular, or even completely novel, way. You could create a web server for Javascript (Node.js), or a client-side app that uses Java (lots of examples).

Comment: Thank you everyone for the clarification, apologies for the stupid question per se, I just didn't know where else to take this and was kind of expecting receiving a brutal beating for this. Thank you all though!

Comment: @AaronBrewer You need to phrase the question without assuming you know something is correct when there is no agreement on what you are talking about.  Unfortunately, even if you do research you will see people talking about things like they know what they are talking about too. :P

Comment: Would also help if you (a) cited your sources, especially for potentially controversial and (b) showed what research you did. For instance, did you google the four permutations of server/client-side java/javascript?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I will remember those the next time, I make presumptions when asking a question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is Java a client-side and server-side language?

It is a language.  It is not specifically client side or server side and it can be used in Blu-ray players and many other devices where there is no client or server.

> Is it more a client-side or server-side, if both are applicable?

It is use more widely on the server side.

> Why does it perform so poorly either way?

It doesn't perform so poorly.  It is less popular on the client as it can require a large download and has suffered some security concerns lately.  It also doesn't run on every device whereas Javascript is more widely supported.

> JavaScript is a client-side language.

Not true,  Javascript can be used in Java and is used on the server side stand alone. see [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)

Comment: Thank you Peter for your informing and answer. Thanks for clearing up the air for me as well.

Comment: @AaronBrewer A common reason for down voting is when you get questions with assumptions which are not correct.  If it doesn't make sense to you there is a good chance it is not true.

Comment: Apologies for assumptions. I have just seen/heard nothing good for Java in the browser but problems.

Comment: @AaronBrewer I don't think there is significantly more problems.  The main reason it is not used IMHO is that GUI developers prefer rapid development and dynamic coding which is something javascript offers.

Answer (score 3):

Java can be used as either.  You can write thick client applications, server applications (web or other), or applets that get embedded in browsers, webstart which is initialized via a browser but launches more like a client-side java application.

Java in the browser is generally a bad idea, there have been many security issues, and, imo (and this is very subjective) it sucks for ui (not the code, but the user experience).

Java has huge market share for server side business applications (web or otherwise) especially in the enterprise space.

Java doesn't perform poorly at all.  It often performs on par with compiled code (such as C++).  The only challenge with Java is that because it is cross-plaform it will sometimes be challenging to work with platform specific things (e.g. directx).

Comment: Thank you Taylor for this! This was more information I sought after! :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a big difference between Java and Javascript.
You might want to look up both.

Javascript is mostly used as client-side language, and Java is most used for applications and or websites.

It's unclear what you mean with poorly performance, you might want to update your question for that part.

Comment: JavaScript is not just client-side language, especially these days.

Comment: @peter.petrov He said "mostly" which still holds, though it's incomplete given the inroads node.js is making.

Comment: Maybe he edited later. OK.

Comment: Javascript is also used in things like queries within MongoDB, etc

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have seen nothing but poor performance reports on Java, and a security concerns, for being in the field for awhile. If you took the time to read my questions and badges, you would see I am not trolling. No question, is a stupid question my friend... But clearly, that's different according to you.

Comment: @peter.petrov I see that now.  Sry.  Robuust, not sure why you think asker is trolling?  He seems to be more web-front-end focused and is trying to understand what java is used for.

Comment: @Taylor edited that, on first sight it looked like it. But the badges made me wonder why

Comment: @AaronBrewer "No question is a stupid question" not sure I agree with that.  The security reports you see are security of Java **IN THE BROWSER**, specifically Applets and Java Webstart.  Both of these are highly problematic and should be disabled for users.  I've  not seen a "poor performance report" for Java in the last ~ 10 years.

Comment: @Taylor, Ahh, I see. That's what I meant by my question, hence the client-side (browser). Thanks for clearing that up.